# My Scrolling Bitmap Canvas is too slow to use

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I am learning to program for the Android. I've made a couple of basic games, but for learning I'd like to make a car driving game. The simplest way I thought of doing this was to keep the car in the middle of the screen and scroll the background to give the illusion of movement.

As an experiment to figure out the engine, I created a 2048x1200 Bitmap which I load from a PNG. This will be the map. I then create a new bitmap of 1024x600 cropped from the map which I display on screen. I do this as getWidth() & getHeight() give these dimensions. I take a different crop each time based on movement to show on screen.

Unfortunately I find this too slow to use. The car would have to move at a snails pace if I wanted it to be smooth. I get about 18fps.

I am using [James Daniello's Simple Game Loop](http://blorb.tumblr.com/post/236799414/simple-java-android-game-loop)

I also read the following stack overflow article which says to keep the object creation out of the main loop as much as possible, which I am doing as best I can.
[How to draw lots of bitmaps on screen in an Android game without slow performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430741/how-to-draw-lots-of-bitmaps-on-screen-in-an-android-game-without-slow-performance)

Also of use was this article by Romain Guy on keeping the Bitmap as the same format as the screen to stop it having to be transformed to be displayed on the screen, which is very costly.
[Bitmap quality, banding and dithering](http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/12/08/bitmap-quality-banding-and-dithering/)

I'd like to figure out the best I can achieve with Canvas and Bitmaps before I move on to OpenGL. Am I at the limitations, or should I do something differently? I find I get 18fps when just scrolling the map 1px at a time for smooth scrolling.

```
private Bitmap track;
private Bitmap visible;
private Point position;
private int fps = 0;
private long lastFpsTime = 0;
private int fpsCount = 0;
Paint pText;

public void Draw(Canvas c){
    visible = Bitmap.createBitmap(track, position.x + 512, position.y + 300, 512, 300);
    position.x++;
    c.drawBitmap(visible, 0,0, null);
    c.drawText("FPS: " + fps, 10, 10, pText);
}

public void Init(Resources resources) {
    // Load Map from track1.png
    track = Bitmap.createBitmap(2048, 1200, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    Bitmap track1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.track1);
    track = track1.copy(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, true);
    position = new Point(0,0);

    //Setup the Text Paint Object
    pText = new Paint();
    pText.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    pText.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
}

public void Update() {
    fpsCount++;

    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastFpsTime >= 1000){
        lastFpsTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        fps = fpsCount;
        fpsCount = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating a new bitmap on every frame you draw. It's extremely expensive. You should use the version of drawBitmap() that takes a source and a destination rectangle instead.

Comment: Excellent thank you for that, I'm now up to 50-55 fps which is more acceptable.  I knew I shouldn't use createBitmap as it is costly, but I incorrectly assumed I had no choice. I assumed drawBitmap and createBitmap did the same thing under the hood. Clearly not.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying and scaling from the original bitmap you can use one of two strategies: a matrix or clipping rectangle. A matrix will allow you to perform all the math related to translation (panning), scaling, skew, and rotation into one object. Each operation is optional too. The operations are calculated with respect to the origin of the Bitmap. The api to use with this is [Canvas.drawBitmap (Bitmap bitmap, Matrix matrix, Paint paint)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Matrix,%20android.graphics.Paint%29). This gives you the greatest control over transforming the Bitmap but to fully use this you'll need to understand some Linear Algebra.

The second option is to use a [rectangle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html), I believe its easier to visualize and work with, in the beginning. Using a source rectangle over the Bitmap you can visualize that as a window that can slide over the dimensions of the Bitmap, also it can be expanded and shrunk as desired. The destination rectangle will represent the dimensions of what you'd like to see on the screen. Often the dimensions of the SurfaceView for a background. Use the [Canvas.drawBitmap (Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, Rect dst, Paint paint)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) API for it.

Comment: I have used the matrix before and I see as you say that it makes sense to use it when you need more that a rectangle. I think I will use it to transform the car sprite for turning, perhaps even scaling for jumping. Once I get this basic engine figured out I will probably try a map at an angle to give 2.5d effect with the car getting smaller when at the back of the tilted map.