# Does using PNG decrease performance on Android Applications?

Tags: android, png

I am currently working on a 2D game in Android Studio and I wish to place a scrolling background. Right now I load the image in as an Asset before the main activity as a png. Once the game starts the png is painted repeatedly to cause the appearance of motion. I've noticed that on my Nexus 4, this greatly decreases performance of the game by slowing down the whole game. I've only tried this on one other phone, which was a Galaxy 6s. On the Galaxy the app did not suffer from such performance issues. So I'm not sure if this is simply a hardware issue of my phone. Any suggestions on how I can improve the performance of my app would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using PNGs doesn't decrease performance, but continuously creating new bitmap objects and drawing them onto the screen will. This question contains a lot of helpful information:

[How to draw lots of bitmaps on screen in an Android game without slow performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430741/how-to-draw-lots-of-bitmaps-on-screen-in-an-android-game-without-slow-performance)

And this one as well:

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8127/android-game-scrolling-background